# How to create copies of variables / constants / placeholders in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed-computing

I am trying to simulate my decentralized algorithm on TensorFlow, so I want to create copies of my `Model` object, which includes variable/placeholder/constant into each of my `Worker` objects. For example, a Model contains

```
self.w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10, 784]))
self.X = tf.placeholder(shape=(BATCH_SIZE, 784), dtype=tf.float32)
```

Now I want to create copies of these things to all `Worker`s so that I can initialize, train and test them separately. Practically, I could use explicit for_loops to create them for each worker, but I am imagining of some `Distributor` object that copies its own dummy model to all workers instead of going deep and manipulate the `Model` objects myself.

I have tried

- `tf.identity`, but its converts Variables to Tensors.
- `copy.deepcopy` simply gives errors.
- record everything the variable has and use `tf.Variable` to re-create them. It's cumbersome and not comprehensive.

Any ideas will be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create a python function which builds your model and call that function multiple times. Be careful about the variable reuse story.

There is in general no way to replicate all state of a graph inside a graph many times safely.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have thought of a way of a better logic: each agent will be assigned their dataset first and given the loss model, I will let them infer the correct sizes of variables and placeholders.

Comment: Hey I'm creating a Variable inside a function and returning the variable back. But one thing is the Variable is being over written . How do i over come this?

Comment: @jackwilson I'd need to see a bit more code to understand what is going on. Can you ask a separate question with more info?

Comment: Hey I already posted the question I'm pasting my link here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54152029/optimizing-extremely-slow-tf-while-loop-for-variable-assignment.